# adding a percentage to a big integer

Tags: javascript

I'm making a cookie clicker game where i recently converted the counter from a number primitive to Big-int and i have faced a problem where i need to add a percentage onto a Big-int. Normally if i would like to add 50% of 1000 to 1000 it would be as easy as multiplying 1000 by 1.5 but you cannot do that with Int's. I am open to ideas on how to solve this issue, any bit helps. What I was originally thinking is that I divide it by 100 and then multiply it by 150 which would give the same results, but the problem is that if the original was below 100 then the fact that it is an int would mess this process up.

Comment: Suppose `x` is your number, then you may try something like this: `(x + x + x) / 2` or `(3 * x) / 2`. That should add 50% to `x`. You may prefer to check if something like `Math.round` is necessary to round-off the decimals.

Comment: You can multiply by 150n before dividing by 100n.
However, it depends on what you want since there is truncation with BigInt. for example 3n * 150n / 100n gives 4n (and not 5n); you can see that there is a remainder (3n * 150n) % 100n == 50n but it's ignored in integer division

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with bigInts too:

```
const bigIntNum = BigInt(123456);
const multipledByTwo = bigIntNum * 2n;
console.log(multipledByTwo);
```

But do make sure the number that you are calculating by multiplying should be in the range of `bigInt`.

To add some percent to the `bigInt` number, you should write the following code:

```
const bigIntNum = BigInt(123456);
//adding 50%
const addedFiftyPercent = bigIntNum + (bigIntNum * 50n) / 100n;
//adding x%
const addedXPercent = bigIntNum + (bigIntNum * xn) / 100n;
```

Comment: @Yolo it is custom here up vote the answer that helped and accept it.